# I have a debugging issue with Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I am debugging a new program by pressing the "Start without deubgging" button, sometimes it will open up a blank program like this:

[image: This is an example]

I can not close these blank programs at all no matter how many times I try and close it, even with the task manager. And if I try to debug it again, it just opens up another blank program. The only way to fix this program is to either restart or shut my computer, but doing that tedious and I don't want to do that every time this happens. Is there a way to prevent this or at least close the blank programs? Thanks!

Comment: The 'blank program' is not the console window of the program you're debugging?

Comment: if you start without debugging, why is the title *debugging issue*? What type of application/project are you working on where you are getting this issue? Or is it for all kinds of projects (web/winforms/console)?

Comment: This is your anti-malware turning viral.  At a minimum you need to make an exclusion.  If it is Avast then get rid of it asap.